# SQL: find duplicate entries with additional filter

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a simple table like so:

```
Name   data
--   ----
A    1
A    2
A    null
B    1
B    null
C    1
D    1
D    2
E    null
E    null
```

I want to get the list of `Name`s that:

- have more than one entry associated with them
- have data column field set to `null` in one of those rows. (or any filter on the value of the data field)

ie, i want to return `A, B, E`

I can do the first part ok but don't know how to do the second part. I tried this:

```sql
select Name from Table1
group by Name
having count(*) > 1
and Score is null;
```

which gives me `E` only, which is not good enough.

I can of course:

- select the full set of Names for which I have data = null, as a subquery
- add a `where Name in (...)` before the group by

something like:

```sql
select Name from Table1
where Name in (
  select distinct Name
  from Table1
  where data is null
)
group by Name
having count(*) > 1;
```

but that's unnecessarily complicated but is also not generic enough. What If I wanted the ones that have at least two null entries? etc.

Is there an easy/clean way of doing this?

Comment: Technically you don't need to distinct within an IN: `1 in (1,1,2,3)` is just as true as `1 IN (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into consideration your additional requirement of "*what if ... at least two null entries*" I would suggest conditional aggregation.

```
select Name from Table1
group by Name
having count(*) > 1 AND SUM(CASE WHEN data IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

That makes it flexible enough, all you would need is to change `> 0` to `> 1` (or any other number).

[**DEMO** (with MySQL)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9rSRQBQ1w1sxHbEKBusbwV/0)

Comment: @CaiusJard - correct. But OP formulated it in `what if`  format so I left it for him to modify.

Comment: @CaiusJard - OK. Spelled it out.

Answer (score 3):

`count(*)` counts all rows.

`count(Score)` counts non-null Score values.

```
select Name from Table1
group by Name
having count(*) > 1               -- more than 1 row
   and count(*) > count(Score)    -- and at least 1 null
```

If you want to add *at least two null entries*:

```
select Name from Table1
group by Name
having count(*) >= count(Score) + 2   -- at least 2 null values
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do intersection of both of your conditions

```
(select Name from Table1
group by Name
having count(*) > 1)
INTERSECT
(select Name from Table1
where Score is null)
```

Comment: Nice use of a rare operator